# Problema con imágenes en ios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ios

tengo un problema con un aplicación que estoy haciendo en Vue js, funciona bien en general, pero cuando veo la sección de imágenes en un dispositivo ios, se pierde el formato, he leído sobre un meta que me puede ayudar, pero no se cual sea, adjunto imagen de como se ve, alguien que me pueda ayudar, por favor?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tendris que agregar como deberia verse, y el codigo necesario para reproducir el problema...